# unwanted duplications with addChild

Tags: swift, swift3, skspritenode, arc4random

First time coder and I thought I would start with a game with Spritekit (Swift 3). I've run across an issue where when I am adding a sprite node to the scene it duplicates it. I should also mention I'm doing this as a reoccurring function where I randomly create one of four obstacles.

I have a timing mechanism set up to make the func run periodically. The func then generates a random number from 0-3 and then uses a switch/case method that should only create 1 of the four options except it always creates 2(still random so it could be 2 duplicates or 2 separate options overlapped). I have also tried a "if, else if..." statement with the same result.

I've already tested this without the timer and without the random number generation and neither of them were the problem leading me to believe its either the "choosing" (switch or else if) method or I'm using addChild wrong.

Any ideas as to what the issue may be, or alternative solutions to randomly generate sprites?

Thanks in advance!

There was a lot more to this code but I've stripped it down to the bear essentials, yet I'm still getting duplicates.

```
let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.height / 2)
let wallOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.height / 4

let xCoordinate = self.frame.midX
let yCoordinate = self.frame.midY + (self.frame.height / 2) + wallOffset


wallTop1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: wallTop1Tex)
wallTop1.scale(to: CGSize(width: wallTop1Tex.size().width / 2, height: wallTop1Tex.size().height / 2))
wallTop1.position = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
wallTop1.zPosition = objectZPos
addChild(wallTop1)
```

Update: I've done more testing and it turns out, according to the node count at least, even when no randomness is involved, two nodes are being created with each addChild func pass. Meaning this code

```
    let xCoordinate = self.frame.midX
    let yCoordinate = self.frame.midY
    objectTex = SKSpriteTexture(imageNamed: "object")
    object = SKSpriteNode(texture: objectTex)
    object.position = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
    self.addChild(object)
```

creates two nodes in my version of sprite kit, which I can only assume is a glitch unless I have some unknown setting set wrong?? If so I would love to hear what it is if not is there some type of deglitching/debugging I can run to fix what seems to be a problem with SpriteKit itself?

Comment: Welcome aboard :) Would you mind adding the code that is causing you problems to your question, it makes it easier for us to get an idea about what is going on.

Comment: @pbodsk I've added the code, let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code above seems fine, you find a start position and then add a new child node, no problem there as far as I can see.

Now...you say:

> except it always creates 2

So, will the above code add two childNodes?...it shouldn't :)

Maybe, and I'm guessing now, your problem is, that this code is run more than once? Remember that each time you call `addChild()`, it adds a new child node, no matter if there is a childNode already or not.

So it could be that you invoke the above code more than once and add a new childNode on top of an existing child node.

#### Removing a Child Node

If that is the case, and if you intend there to be only one childNode, then you could remove your `wallTop1` from its parent before you add it again (I know, removing children from parents, programming is cruel sometimes ;)). A `SKNode` has the method `removeFromParent()` which you can use, so you could do something like:

```
...
if wallTop1 != nil && wallTop1.parent != nil {
    wallTop1.removeFromParent()
}
//And then your "add new node code"
wallTop1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: wallTop1Tex)
wallTop1.scale(to: CGSize(width: wallTop1Tex.size().width / 2, height:wallTop1Tex.size().height / 2))
wallTop1.position = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
...
```

Or...if you don't want any childNodes at all, you can use `removeAllChildren()`, so...something like:

```
removeAllChildren()
//And then your "add new node code"
wallTop1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: wallTop1Tex)
wallTop1.scale(to: CGSize(width: wallTop1Tex.size().width / 2, height:wallTop1Tex.size().height / 2))
wallTop1.position = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
...
```

Or, you could give your `wallTop1` a `name` and then `filter` through your `childNodes` and find that node again:

```
let childNodeName = "somethingCleverHere"
let existingChildren = children.filter { $0.name == childNodeName}
if existingChildren.count > 0 {
   removeChildrenIn(existingChildren!)
}

//And then your "add new node code"
wallTop1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: wallTop1Tex)
wallTop1.scale(to: CGSize(width: wallTop1Tex.size().width / 2, height:wallTop1Tex.size().height / 2))
wallTop1.position = CGPoint(x: xCoordinate, y: yCoordinate)
wallTop1.zPosition = objectZPos
//Remember to give it a name
wallTop1.name = childNodeName
addChild(wallTop1)
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you, good luck :)

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding your answer I don't think that will help. I will be running this code several times, then using a skActionSequence, move them along the screen, then removeFromParent them, with others being created and moved at the same time. My issue is that even though I've stripped out those parts for now I'm still getting two children with the stationary code I've posted above. Is this just a glitch? At this point I can't think of anything else besides the random generation messing with the addChild func??? Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer you the first time, I saw you comment and then just forgot again. It seems odd that even though you only call `addChild` once, you get two nodes added, so I think the error must be somewhere else. I noticed that you wrote: "I've already tested this without the timer and without the random number generation and neither of them were the problem leading me to believe its either the "choosing" (switch or else if) method". But I can not see anything related to "choosing" in the code example you provided. Is that code still present?

Comment: no problem, I though I didn't tag it correctly is the only reason I posted it again. But you are right the "choosing" method isn't the problem either cause that code isn't there right now. I guess I can only wait for an update in Swift and hope it fixes the issue. or come up with an entirley new way to generate the sprites. I've seen a way where you create another parent file entirely with the sprite you want to duplicate, remove the child, and then add it to the main parent screen. so I might give that a shot.